# Is it possible to create a backup of an Azure DevOps organization or project?

Tags: azure-devops, backup, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to backup an Azure DevOps organization or project?
I couldn't find this feature in the organization, project or even pipelines settings.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper?view=azdevops#data-availability) I found that the data is replicated using Azure services such as blob and SQL storage. This is nice, but what if you want to have a copy of your organization in your own server or local computer as, for example, a zip file?
The only possibilities I found were exporting the build and release pipelines and cloning the repositories, but that is far from a complete backup.

Comment: Yes there should be a way to store all the informations gathered in tasks, userstories and other entities, however as of now I have not seen any good solution for this - only the git repos can duplicated on f.ex. github, maybe also on bitbucket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way of doing this as of time of writing (30.01.2019).

You can have builds in yaml (pipelines will be available in yaml shortly). But work items\artifacts\etc are not really exportable.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between having a build in YAML or JSON? Do I benefit in some way by having a build in YAML format? Other than readability as I been comparing a build in both formats.

Comment: yes, json is the import\export format, yaml is the declarative format. yaml can be used to define builds, not create them

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2021**

There are ways of doing this, but they're not all easy or simple:

**1) Manual: Export work items / Download Zip of Repos**

Microsoft document the feature to export items like work items here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/email-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#export-list-as-csv

There is also a way to download your repositories from devops itself:

[image]

The same cant be done for work items but as mentioned below, work items can be retrieved by the rest API.

**2) Manual: Using the REST API / Libgit2sharp**

We used a combination of the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops) and this repo [here](https://github.com/beralves/azure-devops-backup) to automate the scripts for a while. We changed the backup part of the script to instead clone a copy of the code to our blob storage using [Libgit2sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/).

**3) Automatic: Using [Backrightup](https://backrightup.com)**

After struggling with this all ourselves, and having many clients that required this for regulatory reasons (and safety from malicious contractors for instance), we eventually built BackRightUp. [Backrightup](https://backrightup.com) is a backup/restore product specifically for Azure devops. It backs up (and can restore) everything in Azure Devops including work items, repos, wikis, test cases, releases etc.

Comment: I was not happy with the manual download of repos or the use of pipeline to backup all the repos of a specific project.

I wanted to backup the whole code of a complete Organization so I developed my own bash script : https://github.com/lionelpere/azure-devops-repository-backup

Comment: The limitation with the manual export(as of Aug 2022) is that you cannot export attachments and discussions.